# Chrome Driver - Changing Download Folder

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I've had the following code running live now for some time with out any issue until a couple of days ago.

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();

chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", _tempFolder);
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", "true");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--start-maximized");

chrome = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Previously I was having files downloading to my temp folder, but suddenly they are going to the system default of "C:\Users\\Downloads".

I'm using both the latest version of Chrome (62.0.3202.75) and the latest version of Chrome Driver (2.33).

Has anyone else come across this recently?

Comment: Have you tried defining a string named tempFolder and then checking if the directory is changed?

Comment: Add your drivers to a folder in the solution. Set your drivers to always copy to output folder and then call it from your bin/debug folder. This assures they are always found.